# Python Function, get function and arguments as parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments

Note: The referenced duplicate questions doesn't fully answer my current problem.

In Python, I know how to pass a function as an argument, but how to pass its parameters too (which I don't how many they will be. ie a variable number)

for example, I tried:

```
def general_func(func_to_call, args):
   val = func_to_call(args)
   ...
```

But here `args` is one single element, what if the function `func_to_call` takes 2 arguments? I want something like this:

```
general_func(test_function, p1, p2, p3)
```

Plus can I pass None instead of function? I've some cases in which if the user doesn't send parameters to `general_func` then to give `val` a default value.

Comment: I added a second duplicate (that covers passing the collected `*args` to another function). Between the two of them, your question is entirely answered.

Comment: On "can I pass None instead of function?" What would you expect it to do if you passed `None`? Just not call the function and use the default? Where does that come from? The sole non-duplicate part of your question is rather underspecified.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `*` operator.

```
def general_func(func_to_call, *args):
    val = func_to_call(*args)
```

For extra bonus points, use `**` to accept keyword arguments as well.

```
def general_func(func_to_call, *args, **kwargs):
    val = func_to_call(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I've been using kwargs for years, how do i claim my extra bonus points?

Comment: Should also put a `/` so that you're allowed to take a keyword argument called `func_to_call`

Comment: Thanks, but what about my second question of default values for `val` in case no function was provided (I want to allow such thing)

Comment: I can't do `*args = None` which means I can't pass functions which don't take any parameters...

Comment: You want an empty tuple, `()`, not `None`, if you have no args.

Comment: You can use `callable()` to test the function to see if it's callable. If not, return that argument or another value as a default.